# Virtual Handheld Device Testing

Tags: html, css, testing

A service that I often use to see how well my efforts are shaping up in different browsers and OSs is BrowserStack.  Does something of the same ilk exist for testing out the behavior of different mobile devices?  Say for instance I want to check the behavior of a webapp on an iPad, a Galaxy Tab and a Surface.  Is there a service in the cloud that can help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/ - try using for ipad/iphone/android. But I don't think it's ideal solution. Sometimes I use android SDK emulator as well.

Comment: Thanks.  What I was looking for was some way of testing out media queries live on a whole load of devices and ensuring that the query I was writing worked well with the resolution, ppi etc info I have gleaned from various sources.  I guess that just cannot be done for now.